# Can I add some extra lines to default HTML file in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Can I add some extra features in HTML file that is created automatically by VS Code? I mean, when I type html:5 + TAB, I want to get an HTML file that have "style" and "script" tags and some codes (resetting margins and paddings for e.g.) that I usually use. Thanks to everyone who tries to help.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Thank you. I have found the best answer for my question and you triggered it. :)

Answer (score 1):

### Quick workaround:

1. Open Visual Studio Code
2. Go to File > Preferences > User Snippets
3. Select **HTML** from the menu
4. Replace its content with the following

   ```
   {
       "html 5": {
           "prefix": [
               "html:5"
           ],
           "body": [
               "<!DOCTYPE html>",
               "<html lang='en'>",
               "<head>",
               "\t<meta charset='UTF-8'>",
               "\t<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>",
               "\t<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>" ,
               "\t<title>Document</title>",
               "<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet' integrity='sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl' crossorigin='anonymous'>",
               "<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' integrity='sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>",
               "</head>",
               "<body>",
               "",
               "</body>",
               "</html>"
           ],
           "description": "HTML5 code snippet with css and scripts "
       }
   }
   ```

Here you will be overriding the default "html:5" code snippet of vscode. You can edit this "body" content to fit into your favorites. I just made it use bootstrap CSS and Javascript for the demonstration. Now you can type **html:5** and press TAB to get your defined snippet